# How to Cancel all NSURLConnections in Background in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am downloading some Images (approx 200-300 thumb images) on Using NSURLCOnnections. I have array of urls of these images. The connection starts to download these images. But in certain case i want to cancel all these downloading. How it is possible. Can i cancel all these NSURLConnections.

Comment: Do you keep pointers to all that working connections? Perhaps you'd better maintaining a set or array of current connections and so a loop of [connection cancel],[connection release]; is easy to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will be better to create NSOperationQueue and work with NSURLConnection through this queue.

For example:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sendRequest)];


- (void) sendRequest {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
    ...
}
```

NSOperationQueue has method `cancelAllOperations`

Comment: There's also a `NSBlockOperation` which might also be convenient.

Comment: @nielsbot You are absolutely correct NSInvocationOperation can be replaced with NSBlockOperation, maybe this will be even better

Answer (score 2):

`[connection cancel]` is used to cancel an NSURLConnection.

Comment: it was not in the same class. How can i get the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a synchronous `NSURLConnection` in combination with an `NSOperationQueue` to download the data:

```
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
        sendSynchronousRequest:…
        returningResponse:… error:…];
}];
```

This way you can easily control the number of concurrent downloads and cancel the unfinished ones using `[queue cancelAllOperations]`. Note that cancelling the queue won’t stop the downloads that have already started, but that won’t be a problem if you’re downloading just small thumbnails and have a decent concurrent download limit.

Synchronous `NSURLConnection` mode has the advantage of being much easier to use than the asynchronous delegation API.